# WebDriverIO & AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, webdriver, serverless-framework, webdriver-io

I've been working on a project that will run webdriverio (https://webdriver.io/) browser tests inside of an AWS lambda function. I have no problems running locally, but quite a bit of trouble getting it to work inside of the lambda once deployed to AWS.

I have made a public repo that shows what I am attempting to do:
https://github.com/Drewster727/wdio-lambda

If you take a look at that repo, you'll see I'm leveraging the serverless framework (https://serverless.com/) to do the packaging and deploying to AWS. What you'll also see is that my package.json file has some @wdio and chomedriver packages getting installed that should allow me to do what is needed. The trick of course is that the chrome binaries need to be linux compatible (not osx like my local dev environment) -- so that's why the readme states building and packaging inside the lambda docker container.

The problems I'm having are when I execute the function, I check the cloudwatch logs and it tells me an assortment of issues, depending on how I target the chrome binary. In it's current state, errors show [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRegY.png)

Prior to that I'd see issues with the chromedriver failing to start. It's been interesting. I would LOVE to get to a point where I can choose between firefox (gecko) or chromedriver and allow them both to run, but it's tougher than I expected.

I'm looking to see if anyone has tips/suggestions on how I can fix this and get it working. Feel free to fork the repo. I'm stumped!

Thanks,
Drew

Answer (score 1):

I did this about a year back building a tool to essentially use Chrome Driver to walk a site in Lambda. The issues I uncovered is because of issues with the included binaries of the underlying Lambda environment. I cannot remember the exact details about how I corrected the issues I had, but it was related to a specific version of the Chrome driver that did not require a specific set of libraries. This version could be used in Lambda successfully. What that version is I cannot remember but maybe that will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm researching it right now.

I know for sure the guy from Ukraine did it with ProtractorJS. He started 5k tests and they finished within 3 minutes(the longest test time execution).

[The video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=as52JkzIZ3Q&list=PLEUkJQfJdxsTg4al8YrSVp4BxC4ds9biH&index=13) is in Russian language but most slides are in English.
I'll update you if I will be able to implement it soon. 
Or will simply add a post to qalesson.com

Keep trying ;)

Comment: That was me actually ;)

Answer (score 1):

You working with hard and complex task actually, and it has a lot of hidden underwater rocks.

I have some similar project for mocha: https://github.com/Xotabu4/embarrassingly-parallel-mocha , but i didn't finished it to be ready for public usage. It also works with serverless framework as yours project.

First, your issue is because you are running code with ES6 import/export , which node 8 does not support. The easiest solution would be just switch to old good require/module.exports, so you won't be needed webpack/babel to transform your code.

Another thing, check this package, it not documented at all, but might point you to some solutions. https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-lambda-runner

Btw, you should also try Google Functions, i know @boris osipov did some experiments as well - https://github.com/BorisOsipov/wdio-gcloudfunction-example